# Perl XML::LibXML - Cannot replace Replace Element value

Tags: perl, xml-libxml

The XML file looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<application name="pos">
  <artifact id="example.war" type="war" cycle="ReleaseX-Sprint1">
    <jira>tick-1,tick-2,</jira>
    <jenkins>http://localhost:0000/hudson</jenkins>
    <kportal/>
    <scm>
      <transaction id="111" user="user1">
        <file name="a/b/c/d.txt"/>
        <file name="x/y/z.xml"/>
      </transaction>
    </scm>
  </artifact>
</application>
```

I want to add a value to the `kportal` node for a particular artifact node
so that it looks like `<kportal>KPORTAL-1</kportal>`

My code looks like this

```
my $manifestDoc = $manifestFileParser->parse_file($manifestFile);
my $xpathKportal  = qq(//application[\@name="$applicationName"]/artifact[\@id="$artifactID"]/kportal);
my $newdeploymentNode = $manifestDoc->findnodes($xpathKportal);
$newdeploymentNode->removeChildNodes();
$newdeploymentNode->appendText('KPORTAL-1');
```

I am getting the error

```
Can't locate object method "removeChildNodes" via package "XML::LibXML::NodeList"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`XML::LibXML::Node::findnodes`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML%3a%3aLibXML%3a%3aNode) returns a `NodeList` object in scalar context, but a list of nodes in list context. The `NodeList` does not have a `removeChildNodes` method. Suggested solution: Use a list on the left side of `=` to force list context.

```
my ($new_deployment_node) = $manifest_doc->findnodes(...);
```

Comment: my $xpathKportal  = qq(//application[\@name="$applicationName"]/artifact[\@id="$artifactID"]/kportal);
my $var="KPORTAL-1";
for my $kportal_text ($manifestDoc->findnodes($xpathKportal)) { 
   $kportal_text->appendText($var);
}
 I modified my code to above and it has worked.

Answer (score -1):

There are two possbile errors:

You have a typo: $newdeploymentNode ->removeChildNodes();

and maybe your are not using the latest version from XML::LibXML and in this version this method call is not supported.